# grep : how to output the results in a file without the numbered lines?

Tags: grep

I am trying to extract a sub-string from each line in a file between 2 groups of characters :

each line in the input file is :

```
https://github.com/myname/repo1 | GitHub - repo description
https://github.com/myname/repo2 | GitHub - repo description
https://github.com/myname/repo3 | GitHub - repo description
....
https://github.com/myname/repoN | GitHub - repo description
```

I extract the sub-string between "https://github.com/" and " | GitHub" to get  :

```
 myname/repo1
 myname/repo2
 myname/repo3
 ...
 myname/repoN
```

And I use GNU grep. :

```
 grep -nPo 'github.com\/\K.*?(?= \|)' ~/Desktop/forksonGithub.txt
```

This displays the correct list in the console with line number

```
 1:myname/repo1
 2:myname/repo2
 3:myname/repo3
 ...
 4:myname/repoN
```

how can I get this list in an output file without the lin numbers ?
thanks for feedback

Comment: -o flag is enough to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-n` is responsible for the line numbers. You just need to remove it:

```
grep -Po 'github.com\/\K.*?(?= \|)' ~/Desktop/forksonGithub.txt
myname/repo1
myname/repo2
myname/repo3
...
myname/repoN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...  got it ,  I the meantime I used awk -F :'(print$2)' to remove it, so the correct one is. 
grep -Po 'github.com\/\K.*?(?= \|)' ~/Desktop/forksonGithub.txt > result.txt

Comment: -o flag is enough to do it